# Activity Indicator takes time to stop animating

Tags: ios, swift

I am using activity indicator to indicate ongoing network call to the user. But when network call is completed I call  stopAnimating to stop activity Indicator. But activator indicator stay on screen for another 1 to 3 seconds before it disappears.

PS: I am sure no one else is calling activator indicator methods.

```
    class ProgressAnimationView: UIView
{

    static var instance = ProgressAnimationView()
    // MARK: - Properties -

    var backgroundView: UIView
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView

    // MARK: - Methods -

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {

        backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        super.init(frame: frame)



       let vc =  UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.rootViewController
        backgroundView.frame = vc!.view.bounds
        activityIndicator.center = backgroundView.center
        vc?.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
        vc?.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }

    convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }


    // MARK: - Progress Animation



    func startAnimating() {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        backgroundView.hidden = false
    }

    func stopAnimating() {

        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        backgroundView.hidden = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are stopping the activity indicator

Comment: Could you not simply hide the activity indicator rather than call stopAnimating?

Comment: Also, have you set hidesWhenStopped?

Comment: you need to share the code.

Comment: It is possible that you are dismissing it on a background thread. All UI actions should take place on the main thread.

Comment: I have added the code sample. hidesWhenStopped is also not working. It stops but takes some time (about 1 to 3 seconds).

Comment: Where's the code that actually calls your `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` functions?

Comment: Add this to your stopAnimating() function:  `print("Current thread: \(NSThread.currentThread())")`. It should show something like this when run, Current thread: <NSThread: 0x7fa5c3d09360>{number = 1, name = main}. If it does not have 1 & main, then you need to call the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Based on comments given above, I found the issue. `stopAnimating()` was being called from a background thread and was not immediately executed on the processor. To solve the issue I dispatched `stopAnimating()` on the main thread using following code.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        ProgressAnimationView.instance.stopAnimating()
    }
```

Comment: Downvoting because the proposed solution is wrong. The class containing this is a subclass of `UIView`. It's bad design to put any threading code into UI classes. The actual problem was in the client, touching UI from the background.

Comment: I agree with your comment and I have updated the code based on your input.